# Encoding issue. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, json.net, uwp

I'm trying to pass data from my server and display it in a UWP Windows app. The data is stored in a mySQL database

[image]
[image]

This is being output via PHP to a web page here http://www.rwscripts.com/scorealerts/v3/request.php?action=getTeams using this code

```
// Serialize the data structure   
    $result = json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    // Display the XML document   
    header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

    print $result;
```

I'm then reading this in my app with HttpWebRequest and then deserializing the JSON with JSON.net

```
            JArray obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str.Trim()) as JArray;
            if (obj == null || obj.Count == 0) return;

            foreach (NotificationTeam nt in from JObject team in obj
                select
                    new NotificationTeam
                    {
                        Title = team.Value<string>("teamName"),
                        TeamID = team.Value<int>("tid"),
                        Followers = team.Value<int>("followers")
                    })
            {
                nt.Notifications = ScoreManager.GetMgr().GetTeamNotification(nt.TeamID);

                notificationTeams.Add(nt);
            }
```

the output when displayed in my app is like this

[image]

which part of the flow needs to be changed to display the unicode characters correctly?

Comment: did you try `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(yourBytes)`

Comment: Where would you suggest I use that? My web response comes back as a string `StreamReader requestReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    String webResponse = requestReader.ReadToEnd();`

Comment: can you post your actual Unicode characters in text in question instead of picture?

Comment: In the database it is 1. FC KÃƒÂ¶ln the C# output is "1. FC KÃ¶ln" and the json output can be seen in the link above

Comment: you need to change the server connection with SET NAMES utf8 before inserting into Mysql

Comment: Can you post a full code including the HttpWebResponse reading part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way you can fix this beyond the generated json - because it's completely wrong and here is why:

- Special characters in team names (`Köln`) get stored as UTF-8 in your database. 
  `ö` in UTF-8 is `0xc3` `0xb6`.
- The output data however is then encoded (or just formatted) **again** as UTF-16 (aka `Encoding.Unicode` in C#)
  Here is where the trouble starts. `ö` in UTF-16 (and UTF-32) is `0x00` `0xf6`.
- The UTF-8 character bytes get encoded as two **separate** UTF-16 characters `\u00c3` and `\u00b6` instead of just **`\u00f6`**. So instead of **one utf-8** character, you end up with **two utf-16** characters (that represent two bytes of the same utf-8 character).
- Your app recognises the `\u` escape sequences and turns them (completly right from its point of view) into two separate UTF-16 characters (`Ã¶`).

Long story short, this is what happens to your strings:

`ö` in UTF-32 is `f6000000`
`ö` in UTF-16 is `f600`
`ö` in UTF-8 is `3c` `b6`

1. `Köln` (Input)
2. `K[0xc3][0xb6]ln` (Sql UTF-8)
3. `K\u00c3\u00b6ln` (Json UTF-8 encoded as UTF-16)
4. `KÃ¶ln` (C# UTF-16 decoded)

Since [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) expects a UTF-8 string, I suspect the problem occurs somewhere between the database and the encoding (php).

This post might give you a hint to where the encoding settings might be inconsistent:

[UTF-8-all-the-way-through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

In case you need to tinker with your settings, the output you will want is:

`"teamName": "1. FC K\u00f6ln"` or `"teamName": "1. FC Köln"` (should be fine too)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this ..

```
$result = json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

.. maybe this .. ?

```
$result = json_encode($data,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

.. or both.. ?

```
$result = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: I tried this. It changes the html output but makes no difference to the app output

Comment: Well, I can't propose anything further, as I am not doing anything in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to get bytes of your `Unicode` characters and covert it to `String`.

```
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(NotificationTeam.Title);
NotificationTeam.Title = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

OR

```
new NotificationTeam
                    {
                        Title = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(team.Value<string>("teamName"))),
                        TeamID = team.Value<int>("tid"),
                        Followers = team.Value<int>("followers")
                    })
```

Comment: Doing the latter I get the output "1\0.\0 \0F\0C\0 \0K\0?\0?\0l\0n\0" which is displayed as 1. FC K??ln in the app

Comment: what is your expected value?

Comment: try using https://dotnetfiddle.net/ to create your problem; execute below code there `using System;
using System.Text;
     
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
  var unicode = "FC KÃƒÂ¶ln";
  Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(unicode)));
 }
}`

Comment: It should be 1. FC Köln

Comment: which language it is?

Comment: It's German. Using the json output `"1. FC K\u00c3\u00b6ln"` I also get ?? in dotnetfiddle.net using your code above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112547/discussion-between-real-world-and-techspider).

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the bug in .NET Connector. In this case, you should specify

```
character_set_server=utf8mb4
```

in the config or `[--character-set-server=utf8mb4][1]` in the mysqld arguments